# post setState evaluation of state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a react component, I update `state` in various ways, but I would like to do an evaluation (call a function) after the state was updated.

When I do the following, `secondUpdate()` does not access to the updated `state`, so it is one cycle late:

```
firstUpdate = e => {
    this.setState({ email: e.state.value });
    // ... some validation
    secondUpdate();
}
secondUpdate() {
    const allValid= this.state.aIsValid & this.state.bIsValid & this.state.cIsValid;
    this.setState({ allIsValid: allValid });
}
```

How should I bind `secondUpdate()` to any or some `state` update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setState callback` :

```
this.setState({ email: e.state.value } , () => {
   // Will get called once the state is updated
   // ... some valdidations
   secondUpdate();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`allIsValid` shall not be a state at all. By having states that depend on each other, you risk that states get out of sync, and your logic breaks. Instead, as `allIsValid` is derived from other states, it can just be calculated based on the state inside render:

```
 render() {
   const { email } = this.state;
   const allIsValid = email.length > 5 && /*...*/;
    // ...
 }
```

Comment: Yes, this definitely seems like an X/Y problem. The term for this is *derived* state and you should not make it part of the state of your component

Comment: This is definitely much better way to do.

Comment: what in case of remote validations?

Comment: @VivekDoshi it depends, but that doesn't seem to be the case here

Comment: Can you develop the risks ? So far it's just a claim. Beside this, how do you address the situation where the rendered html depends on `this.state.allIsValid` without `this.state`?

Comment: A remark: you want to use & not && if you want "all to be valid", not "at least one is valid".

Comment: @Soleil to see examples what happens if your states get out of sync, try one of the other answers. Also `&` is a bitwise and, I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @JonasWilms `A&&B` won't evaluate B is A is true. What is out of sync ? You still don't address the rendering depending on `this.state.allIsValid`

Comment: @JonasWilms, if you can manage the state properly there is no issue, people generally uses more states this.

Comment: @VivekDoshi if I input data (e.g. the email) till it gets valid, then change stuff until it is invalid, there is a small timespan where `email` is invalid but `allIsValid` is true. Most of the times you won't notice it, because this *should*  happen in a few milliseconds. But on slow clients, a user might be able to submit it before the state updates.

Comment: @Soleil you can access `allIsValid` inside `render()` ? I don't get the problem at all. Also please read a bit more about boolean algebra before you try to educate others ... I certainly know what I'm doing ....

Comment: @JonasWilms You're right, I messed up with the &/&&. I could access `allIsValid`, but if only it is updated, there is no re-rendering; I understand that you're way works only if `this.state` is changed in conjonction with `allIsValid`; and that's not want I want.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to go through this:
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you
> should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.
>
> To fix it, use a second form of setState() that accepts a function
> rather than an object. That function will receive the previous state
> as the first argument, and the props at the time the update is applied
> as the second argument:

```
this.setState({
    // change the state
}, () => {
 //Perform something after the state is updated.
})
```

Comment: `Perform something after the state is updated`, this is where you can update the state, it s not callback, please do read the doc you have provided in answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `componentDidUpdate()`.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
   // code from secondUpdate() 
}
```

Here is [official](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) doc